# Extended Euclidean and Bezout's

Tags: discrete-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm

Given two numbers, $a_0 = 172, a_1 = 61$

Write the the extended Euclidean algorithm and Bezout’s coefficients $x_k$ and $y_k$, i.e. the numbers such that the following equation is satisfied:
$x_k a_0 + y_k a_1 = \gcd(a_0, a_1)$

I wrote out all the steps but there is something wrong with my x coefficient and can't figure out where I went wrong:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
{} & x & y\\
\hline
a_0=172 & x_0= 1 & y_0=0\\
a_1=61 & x_1= 0 & y1=1\\
172=2(61)+50 & 1-2(0) & 0-2(1)\\
a_2=50 & x_2=1 & y_2=-2\\
61=1(50)+11 & 0-1(1) & 1-1(2)\\
a_3=11 & x_3=-1 & y_3=3\\
50=4(11)+6 & 1-4(1) & -2-4(3)\\
a_4=6 & x_4=5 & y_4=-14\\
11=1(6)+5 & -1-1(5) & 3-1(-14)\\
a_5=5 & x_5=-6 & y_5=17\\
6=1(5)+1 & 5-1(-6) & -14-1(17)\\
a_6=1 & x_6=11 & y_6=-31
\end{array}
$$
Thus $1=9(172)+(-31)(61)$.

Comment: It appears that $$5\neq -4\cdot 172+17\cdot 61$$ whereas $$5=-6\cdot 172+17\cdot 61$$ which reveals the error of having $-1-1\cdot 5=-4$ in that step.

Comment: @String thanks, I see that now. So how can I fix that? or does it mean that these two numbers are not relative primes

Comment: Just correct $x_5$ and continue on from there.

Comment: @Csci319: They are relatively prime. Only $-1-1\cdot 5$ is not equal to $-4$ but to $-6$, which should fix your problem.

Comment: ahh I see, when I am doing these problems it takes me a while to see that I just  made a simple algebraic mistake. thanks so much

Comment: so the multiplicative inverse of $61 mod 172$ is $-31$. Is that correct?